# python (scipy): How to find multiple roots of an equation by passing in the jacobian as well

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

**Problem Statement:**

Consider the following code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def func(x, y):
    out = 2 * np.arccos(1-x) - np.sin(2 * np.arccos(1- x)) - y
    return out

def jac(x,y):
    out = 4 * np.sin(np.arccos(1 - x))
    return out

initial_guesses = np.array([0.25, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5])
args = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5,)
multiple_roots = optimize.root(func, x0 = initial_guesses, method='hybr', 
                                                          args=(args,))
```

Everything works fine.

**Passing in the Jacobian**

But I also want to pass in the `jacobian` I calculated above as well. When I do:

```
initial_guesses = [0.25, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5]
args = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5,)
multiple_sol_with_jac = optimize.root(func, x0 = initial_guesses, method='hybr', 
                                      args=(args,), jac=jac)
```

**Error:**

It gives me the following error
`TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'fprime' argument 'jac'.Shape should be (5, 5) but it is (5,)`

A similar question was asked [here](http://TypeError:%20fsolve:%20there%20is%20a%20mismatch%20between%20the%20input%20and%20output%20shape%20of%20the%20'fprime'%20argument%20'jac'.Shape%20should%20be%20(5,%205)%20but%20it%20is%20(5,)). But it does not address passing in the `jacobian` when using `scipy.optimize.root` to find multiple roots.

**Attempt:**
Obviously we want to account now for the fact that we have a list of points at which we seek roots. So the jacobian needs to be appropriately modified to output a matrix rather than a scaler. I tried doing `jac = [jac] * 5` but it doesn't work.

**Question**:
How do I pass in the `jacobian` appropriately in this case?

Comment: Step 1: figure out the correct Jacobian, because that's clearly not it.

Comment: (As in, before even writing any code, figure out what the mathematically correct Jacobian matrix would be.)

Comment: How about diagonalizing the Jacobian; return a 2d array, `np.diag(out)`?

Comment: Are you trying to optimize a function of a scalar? You'll probably be better served just calling `scipy.optimize.root` in a loop.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to optimize a function of a scaler. If I pass in a list of initial guesses and then a list of args it gives me exactly what I am looking for. I just need a way to figure out how to pass in the jacobian as well. A loop will mostly likely make the code less efficient, right?

Comment: The actual problem has thousands of data points at which I seek the root. That is why I want to get this to work.

Comment: SciPy is not vectorizing `scipy.optimize.root` over your guesses; it is treating your function as a multidimensional function with 5 inputs and 5 outputs, whose Jacobian should have 25 entries. If you try to find 5000 roots this way, it will expect a 25 million entry Jacobian. This is unlikely to be efficient. I recommend using a single-dimensional solver, probably [`scipy.optimize.brentq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html#scipy.optimize.brentq), and searching for one root at a time.

Comment: Okay. Let me try that.